# How to migrate from Dropbox API1 to API2 - Objective C

Tags: objective-c, dropbox-api

With the impending demise of the Objective-C API for Dropbox I am looking to migrate a few simple calls.

I was able to migrate to the authenticate without issue, but am having trouble finding replacements for the following API.  Was hoping someone might be able to help:

Calls out:

```
[restClient loadMetadata:@"/"];
[restClient uploadFile:fileName toPath:destDir withParentRev:rev fromPath:path];
[restClient loadFile:@"" into:localpath];
```

Callbacks:

```
-(void) restClient:(DBRestClient *)client loadedMetadata:(DBMetadata *)meta{}
-(void) restClient:(DBRestClient *)client uploadedFile:(NsString *)destpath from:(NSString *) srcPath metadata:(DBMetadata *) meta {}
-(void) restClient:(DBRestClient *)client loadedFile:(NsString *)localpath contenttype:(NSString *) type metadata:(DBMetadata *) meta {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you're referring to using the [official Objective-C SDK for Dropbox API v2](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-obj-c), in which case:

- `loadMetadata` -> [`getMetadata`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-obj-c/api-docs/latest/Classes/DBFILESRoutes.html#/c:objc(cs)DBFILESRoutes(im)getMetadata:) or [`listFolder`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-obj-c/api-docs/latest/Classes/DBFILESRoutes.html#/c:objc(cs)DBFILESRoutes(im)listFolder:)/[`listFolderContinue`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-obj-c/api-docs/latest/Classes/DBFILESRoutes.html#/c:objc(cs)DBFILESRoutes(im)listFolderContinue:)
- `uploadFile` -> [`uploadData`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-obj-c/api-docs/latest/Classes/DBFILESRoutes.html#/c:objc(cs)DBFILESRoutes(im)uploadData:inputData:)
- `loadFile` -> [`downloadData`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-obj-c/api-docs/latest/Classes/DBFILESRoutes.html#/c:objc(cs)DBFILESRoutes(im)downloadData:)

There are also other versions of these methods, so be sure to check out the rest of the documentation to choose what you need for your use case.